# Can someone explain why there is a lack of symmetry in accessing methods from smypy

Tags: python, python-import, sympy

I know quite a bit about core python, but the class part is somewhat of a mystery to me.

For example I’m having difficulty understanding

sympy.ntheory.primetest

The documentation for sympy includes a primality test  assessable as

```
   sympy.ntheory.primetest.isprime(n)
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#sympy.ntheory.primetest.isprime

So if I want to reference isprime without all the preceding stuff, I can do

(1)  from sympy.ntheory.primetest import isprime

and then  isprime(31) for example,  will return True.

However I can also do

(2) from sympy.ntheory import isprime

and then isprime(31) will also work. So the primetest part is redundant.

So the question is why do both (1) and (2) work?

I would have thought just (1) would work.

To add further confusion, consider  is_square

Here we have, according to the documentation,

sympy.ntheory.primetest.is_square

but in order to use is_square by itself I must do

from sympy.ntheory.primetest import is_square

whereas if I do

```
 from sympy.ntheory import is_square
```

I get an error

ImportError: cannot import name 'is_square' from 'sympy.ntheory'

So there seems to be a lack of symmetry with  some of these methods.

In the is_square case I needed to include primetest in the import statement in order to avoid getting an error, whereas for isprime it made no difference if I included primetest or omitted it. Why is there a difference?

Comment: Strictly speaking these are functions, not methods.  They aren't bound to a class or instance of a class. So import can be more flexible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is often refereed to as "re-exporting" names. Essentially, the authors of `sympy` chose to strip away a level of module-namespacing to make importing commonly used functions more convenient.

`sympy.ntheory`'s `__init__.py` includes the import

```py
from .primetest import isprime, is_gaussian_prime
```

as well as the [`__all__` export](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44834/11082165)

```py
__all__ = [
    # ...
    'isprime', 'is_gaussian_prime',
    # ...
]
```

This exposes the function `isprime` from `sympy.ntheory.primetest` as an member of `sympy.ntheory`, and allows `isprime` to be glob imported with `from sympy.ntheory import *`. As you noted, not all names in the `ntheory` submodules are re-exported in this way. Names that are not re-exported (like `is_square`) must be accessed through their defining submodule.

Comment: Also, sympy's `__init__.py` does the same thing, so you could even write `from sympy import isprime`.